# MVC Equivalent of a Postback on Button Click

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I am an MVC newbie. I am trying to update a page after a button click. The button click event calls a javascript function that does the following:

```
function buttonClickHandler(e) {
        switch(e.id)
        {
            case "btnRefresh":
                alert('Refresh Code');
                break;

            case "btnLatest":
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("DashboardHome", "Dashboard")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        SeriesParameters: {
                            BankID: "48",
                            CompanyID: "0"
                        },
                        DateModifier: "latest"
                    },
                    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                        alert('Done');
                        // handle success
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(error);
                        // handle error
                    }
                });
                break;

            case "btnMTD":
                alert('MTD Code');
                break;
        }
    }
```

The controller is the following:

```
 public ActionResult DashboardHome(ChartDataModel model)
 {
      return View(ChartDataController.GetChartData(model.SeriesParameters));  
 }
```

Initially the view loads fine (it's a toolbar with datepickers and 3 Kendo Charts). I click the button and as you can see it calls the action with some hardcoded parameters that should change the chart data and the dates in the datepickers.

Debugging shows the new parameters make it to the controller and the ChartData is updated correctly. But the charts and the datepickers don't actually update with the new data.

I suspect it has to do with using the $.ajax command, but not sure.

Any clues? Thanks!

EDIT:

this is the full View

```
@using SampleMVCWeb.Models
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model ChartDataModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard Home";
}


<div id="divTitle" style="height:40px">
    <h2>Dashboard</h2>
</div>
<div id="divToolbar" style="height:45px">
@(Html.Kendo().ToolBar()
    .Name("ToolBar")
    .Items(items =>
    {
        items.Add().Template("<div><label>Start Date: </label></div>");
        items.Add().Template("<input id='dpStart' />");
        items.Add().Type(CommandType.Separator);
        items.Add().Template("<div><label>End Date: </label></div>");
        items.Add().Template("<input id='dpEnd' />");
        items.Add().Type(CommandType.Separator);
        items.Add().Type(CommandType.Button).Text("Refresh").Id("btnRefresh").Click("buttonClickHandler");
        items.Add().Type(CommandType.Button).Text("Latest").Id("btnLatest").Click("buttonClickHandler");
        items.Add().Type(CommandType.Button).Text("Month-To-Date").Id("btnMTD").Click("buttonClickHandler");
        items.Add().Type(CommandType.Separator);
        items.Add().Template("<div><label><input id='rbtItemCount' type='radio' name='chartType' onclick='RadioClick(this)' value='cnt' checked='true'>&nbspItem Count</label></div>");
        items.Add().Template("<div><label><input id='rbtAmount' type='radio' name='chartType' onclick='RadioClick(this)' value='amt'>&nbspAmount</label></div>");
    })
)
<script>
var defaultStart = new Date("@Model.SeriesParameters.StartDate.ToShortDateString()");
var defaultEnd = new Date("@Model.SeriesParameters.EndDate.ToShortDateString()");

$(document).ready(function () {
        alert('start');
        $("#dpStart").kendoDatePicker({
            format: "MM/dd/yyyy",
            value: kendo.toString(defaultStart, "MM/dd/yyyy")
        });

        $("#dpEnd").kendoDatePicker({
            format: "MM/dd/yyyy",
            value: kendo.toString(defaultEnd, "MM/dd/yyyy")
        });

        var datepicker = $("#dpStart").data("kendoDatePicker");

        datepicker.bind("change", function () {
            var value = this.value();
            alert(value); //value is the selected date in the datepicker
        });

    });

    function buttonClickHandler(e) {
        switch(e.id)
        {
            case "btnRefresh":
                alert('Refresh Code');
                break;

            case "btnLatest":
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("DashboardHome", "Dashboard")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        SeriesParameters: {
                            BankID: "481",
                            CompanyID: "0"
                        },
                        DateModifier: "latest"
                    },
                    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                        alert('Done');
                        $(someElement).html(data);
                        // handle success
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(error);
                        // handle error
                    }
                });
                break;

            case "btnMTD":
                alert('MTD Code');
                break;
        }
    }

    function RadioClick(radioButton)
    {
        var sdatepicker = $("#dpStart").data("kendoDatePicker");
        var startDate = sdatepicker.value();
        var edatepicker = $("#dpEnd").data("kendoDatePicker");
        var endDate = edatepicker.value();

        switch(radioButton.value)
        {
            case "cnt":
                alert('Load charts by item count.');
                $("#chtItemsByType").data("kendoChart").reload();
                break;
            case "amt":


                alert(kendo.toString(startDate, "MM/dd/yyyy"));
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("DashboardHome", "Dashboard")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    SeriesParameters: {
                        BankID: "48",
                        CompanyID: "0",
                        StartDate: kendo.toString(startDate, "MM/dd/yyyy"),
                        EndDate: kendo.toString(endDate, "MM/dd/yyyy"),
                        PercentByItemCount: false
                    }
                }
                //,
                //success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                //    alert('Done');
                //    // handle success
                //},
                //error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                //    alert(error);
                //    // handle error
                //}
            });
            break;
    }
}

function GetDate() {
    alert("Got it!");
}
</script>
```

```
<div id="divCharts" style="height:calc(100% - 85px);">
<div id="topRow" style="height:50%;width:100%">
    <div id="divSpaceTopLeft" style="height:100%;width:5%;float:left">

    </div>
    <div id="divItemsByType" style="height:100%;width:45%;float:left;vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;">
        <div style="display:none;vertical-align:middle;">
            <h4><label id="lblItemsByType">Items By Type: No Data</label></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="chart-wrapper">
            @(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model.SeriesData.ElementAt(0))
                .Name("chtItemsByType")
                .Title(title => title
                    .Text("Items By Type")
                    .Position(ChartTitlePosition.Top)
                )
                .Legend(legend => legend
                    .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Left)
                )
                .Series(series =>
                {
                    series.Pie(
                        model => model.ItemCount,
                        model => model.ItemType,
                        null,
                        model => model.Exploded
                        )
                        .Labels(labels => labels
                            .Visible(true)
                            .Template("#= dataItem.ItemCount#")
                        )
                        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                            .Visible(true)
                            .Template("#= dataItem.ItemAmountDisplay# #= dataItem.YValue# %")
                        );                        
                })
                .Theme("Bootstrap")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:100%;" })           
            )
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divExceptionItemsByStatus" style="height:100%;width:45%;float:right">
        <div style="display:none;vertical-align:middle;">
            <h4><label id="lblExceptionItems">Exception Items By Status: No Data</label></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="chart-wrapper">
            @(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model.SeriesData.ElementAt(1))
                .Name("chtExceptionItemsByStatus")
                .Title(title => title
                    .Text("Exception Items By Status")
                    .Position(ChartTitlePosition.Top)
                )
                .Legend(legend => legend
                    .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Right)
                )
                .Series(series =>
                {
                    series.Pie(
                        model => model.ItemCount,
                        model => model.ItemType,
                        null,
                        model => model.Exploded
                        )
                        .Labels(labels => labels
                            .Visible(true)
                            .Template("#= dataItem.ItemCount#")
                        )
                        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                            .Visible(true)
                            .Template("#= dataItem.ItemAmountDisplay# #= dataItem.YValue# %")
                        )
                        .StartAngle(180);
                })
                .Theme("Bootstrap")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:100%;" })
            )
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divSpaceTopRight" style="height:100%;width:5%;float:left"></div>
</div>
<div id="bottomRow" style="height:50%;width:100%;">
    <div id="divSpaceLeft" style="height:100%;width:15%;float:left"></div>
    <div id="divTop5" style="height:100%;width:70%;float:left;text-align:center">
        <div style="display:none;vertical-align:middle;">
            <h4><label id="lblTop5">Top 5 Companies: No Data</label></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="chart-wrapper">
            @(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model.SeriesData.ElementAt(2))
                .Name("chtTop5")
                .Title(title => title
                    .Text("Top 5 Companies")
                    .Position(ChartTitlePosition.Top)
                )
                .Legend(legend => legend
                    .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Left)
                )
                .Series(series =>
                {
                    series.Pie(
                        model => model.ItemCount,
                        model => model.ItemType,
                        null,
                        model => model.Exploded
                        )
                        .Labels(labels => labels
                            .Visible(true)
                            .Template("#= dataItem.ItemCount#")
                        )
                        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                            .Visible(true)
                            .Template("#= dataItem.ItemAmountDisplay# #= dataItem.YValue# %")
                        );
                })
                .Theme("Bootstrap")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:100%;" })
            )
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divSpaceRight" style="height:100%;width:15%;float:left"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your not doing anything with the data you return in the success callback. Your returning html (it should be `return PartialView(..)` not `return View(..)`) so you need to update the DOM - say `$(someElement).html(data);`

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I am not sure where/how I would do that. The data that is returned is the full HTML for the page. How would I reload the whole page? I added the view HTML.

Comment: I accidentally added: $(someElement).html(data); in the code

Comment: If you want to reload the whole page, don't use ajax. Just do a form submit and redirect

Comment: Sorry for being new, can you give an example of how to do that from javascript still passing the model data? I have been looking for an example of that everywhere!

Comment: Not sure what your really wanting to do. If your only updating part of the page (e.g. just a chart) then ajax is appropriate, but if you want to update the whole page, then you should be just submitting a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't understanding the basics of how MVC works. I think I got it now. The ajax call should be a call to update a certain part of the page (in my example the #divCharts). So the jquery is:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("UpdateCharts", "Dashboard")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    SeriesParameters: {
                        BankID: "48",
                        CompanyID: "0"
                    },
                    DateModifier: "latest"
                },
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    $('#divCharts').html(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(error);
                    // handle error
                }
            });
```

And then I created another action on the controller:

```
public PartialViewResult UpdateCharts(ChartDataModel model)
{
    return PartialView("_DashboardCharts", ChartDataController.GetChartData(model.SeriesParameters));
}
```

Where '_DashboardCharts' is a new .cshtml file that only contains the HTML that should be included in "divCharts" (thus 'PartialView'). The jquery '$('#divCharts').html(data)' tells the page to fill that div with the HTML contained in the data object.

I'm sure this is basic to many people but to beginners coming from WebForms it is very different conceptually!